# numpy.logical_and.reduce on pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

The versions are *python==3.6.6*, *pandas==0.23.0*, *numpy==1.15.0*. I want to get the intersection of a list of DataFrames.

For example,

```
x = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(6).reshape((3, 2)),
    index=["a", "b", "c"],
    columns=["q", "e"]
)

y = x - 1
```

The expected return is what *np.logical_and(x, y)* returns

```
       q      w
a  False  False
b   True   True
c   True   True
```

However, *np.logical_and.reduce([x, y])* raises and error:

> ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 3 to array axis with dimension 2

Then, I tried

```
x = pd.DataFrame(
    np.arange(4).reshape((2, 2)),
    index=["a", "b"],
    columns=["q", "e"]
)

y = x - 1
np.logical_and.reduce([x, y])
```

Another Error shows up:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'q'

Answer (score 1):

Instead of doing:

```
np.logical_and.reduce([x, y])
```

do:

```
np.logical_and.reduce([x.values, y.values])
```

**output**:

```
[[False False]
 [ True  True]
 [ True  True]]
```

The first one applies the operation to DataFrame (not numpy arrays) the second one applies the operation to the values of the DataFrame `x.values` represented as numpy arrays;

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 
              'col2': [7, 45, 12, 56, 14],
              'col3': [56, 67, 8, 12, 39],
              'col4': [16, np.nan, 25, 6, 19],
              'col5': [1, 9, 23, 56, np.nan],
              'col6': [13, 3, 53, 72, 88]})
print(df)
df2 = (df%2).replace(1, np.nan)==0
print('\n',df2)
print('\nOdd numbers mean {}'.format([df[col][np.logical_and.reduce([df2[col].values == False])].mean() for col in df.columns]))
print('\nEven numbers mean {}'.format([df[col][np.logical_and.reduce([df2[col].values == True])].mean() for col in df.columns]))
```